# Glance won't appear anymore - No glance associated to App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit

I created an iOS project (I am using XCode 6.4) and whenever I build and run the target for Apple Watch the Glance will not appear anymore.

I am not sure what happened. **I also tried to recreate the Glance controller in the storyboard but the compiler does not seem to detect it and hence install it in the App** (there is no glance associated to the App).

I tried to modify other UI assets in the watch interface storyboard and they do get modified, so I am definitely using the right storyboard.

Any help?

Comment: you can try dropping and adding your own app in Glances section of your phone's Apple Watch app.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But I deleted and re-added a Glance Interface controller in the storyboard which does not get loaded/installed in the App bundle. Previously it worked perfectly. It seems that the Glance controller does not get loaded from the interface.storyboard.. how can I force load it?

Comment: are you testing in the simulator or device? If you are testing on an actual iPhone/Watch pair, you can try the Apple Watch app on your iPhone to set which glances should appear in what order. My suggestion was/is to drop the your from glances list there and re-add it.

Comment: Hello! This does the job! Thank you very much, please add it as answer. The Show in Glance setting from the App in the iPhone Watch app was deactivated. Not sure why it got deactivated, but the important thing is that now the problem is solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're testing on physical devices, you can try dropping and re-adding your own app in Glances list of your phone's Apple Watch app. It should refresh the glances on your watch.

[image]
[image]